# Extracting and print jsession id value from Url in loadrunner trueclient script

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to extract and print jsession id value from Url in loadrunner trueclient script.Could anybody please guide me how to do the same.

Sample Url is as below:
Https://sometext.com/abcd/ab/abc_xyz;jsessionid=1234FG_ABCD14EFGH67ijkldfui:12ab7cd9

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pull this out of the HTTP access logs as one of the parameter data field collected?